# Array Re arrange in React js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have some array objects for listing.

based on the list, if the user clicks the particular list item from the objects,

need to show the particular clicked list item as first.

```
var list = [
 {
  tradeareaid: "80"
  tradeareaname: "test1"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "81"
  tradeareaname: "test2"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "82"
  tradeareaname: "test3"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "83"
  tradeareaname: "test4"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "84"
  tradeareaname: "test5"
 },
]
```

in the list If I selected trade area 83 means I needed the list like below

```
var list = [
 { 
  tradeareaid: "83"
  tradeareaname: "test4"
 },
 {
  tradeareaid: "80"
  tradeareaname: "test1"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "81"
  tradeareaname: "test2"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "82"
  tradeareaname: "test3"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "84"
  tradeareaname: "test5"
 },
]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `tradeareaid` of the item which is clicked and use the `getSortedList` function (in a click event handler) to get the new list something like this :

```js
var list = [
 {
  tradeareaid: "80",
  tradeareaname: "test1"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "81",
  tradeareaname: "test2"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "82",
  tradeareaname: "test3"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "83",
  tradeareaname: "test4"
 },
 { 
  tradeareaid: "84",
  tradeareaname: "test5"
 },
]

function getSortedList(id){
  const clickedItem = list.find(item=>item.tradeareaid===id)
  const filterdList = list.filter(item=>item.tradeareaid!==id)
  return [clickedItem,...filterdList]
}
const sortedList = getSortedList(list[3].tradeareaid)
console.log({sortedList})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some key for sort onclick

```js
var list = [ { tradeareaid: "80", tradeareaname: "test1" }, { tradeareaid: "81", tradeareaname: "test2" }, { tradeareaid: "82", tradeareaname: "test3" }, { tradeareaid: "83", tradeareaname: "test4" }, { tradeareaid: "84", tradeareaname: "test5" }, ]

//if test4 was clicked 

clicked = 3; // index
list.forEach((a, b) => {
  list[b]['key'] = b;
  if (b == clicked) {
    list[b]['key'] = -1;
  }
})

console.log(list.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key))
```